# Can a product of unbounded functions be a bounded function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am supposed to answer the question if a product of unbounded functions can be a bounded function. I have found two unbounded functions (direct proportionality and inverse proportionality) and their product is a bounded function, thus I have found a counter example. Is my solution correct? Thanks

Comment: So your answer is for example $x$ and $1/x$ defined for positive $x$?

Comment: Basically I want to know if finding a counter example is enough to answer to the question.

Comment: Is that a counter example though? If the statement is: the product of two unbounded functions is unbounded then you have found a counterexample. If the statement is what you wrote above then you have found an example that it is in fact true that: ''a product of unbounded functions can be a bounded function''

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct. The functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ are both unbounded on the positive real numbers, but their product is constant.